# How to use distance to extract features and compare images: : matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to code for feature extraction from the two  images, which are actually similar. I tried to extract the intersection points from both of the image and calculated the distance from one intersection point to all other points. This procedure was iterated for all points and in both images.

Then I compared the distance between points in both images But I found that even for dissimilar images am getting same kind of distance and am not able to distinguish them.

Is there any way in this method which will improve the code or is there any other way to find the similarity.

```
I = bwmorph(I,'skel',Inf);
II = bwmorph(II,'skel',Inf);
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(I),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(I,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
[i1,j1] = ind2sub(size(II),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(II,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
figure,imshow(I); hold on; plot(j,i,'rx');
figure,imshow(II); hold on; plot(j1,i1,'rx')
m=size(i,1);
n=size(j,1);
m1=size(i1,1);
n1=size(j1,1);
for x=1:m
   for y=1:n
       d1(y,x)=round(sqrt((i(y,1)-i(x,1)).^2+(j(y,1)-j(x,1)).^2));
   end
end
for x1=1:m1
    for y1=1:n1
       dd1(y1,x1)=round(sqrt((i1(y1,1)-i1(x1,1)).^2+(j1(y1,1)-j1(x1,1)).^2));
    end
end
size(d1);
k1=reshape(d1,1,m*n);
k=sort(k1);
k=unique(k);

size(dd1);
k2=reshape(dd1,1,m1*n1);
k2=sort(k2);
k2=unique(k2);

z = intersect(k,k2)
length(z);
if length(z)>20
    disp('similar images');
else
    disp('dissimilar images');
end
```

This is a part of my code where I tried to extract features.
input1
[image]
input2
[image]
skel 1[image]
skel2 [image]

Comment: You're sorting the distances instead of using them in the order in which they appear. This may be the issue. Try comparing the difference without sorting.

Comment: @optimist I did the code without sorting too but still am not able to  match the images.sometimes number of matching distance occurs more in dissimilar images. About sorting, am not an expert but asking out of curiosity, how sorting will affect the result, because  I guess sorting is done to arrange the elements in a matrices in a particular order.

Comment: Can you post your original images without the red x's?

Comment: @Cecilia I have added the input images and the processed image also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is not the problem. Instead, it seems that either your feature descriptor is not powerful enough or your comparison method is not powerful enough, or a combination of the two. This gives us several options for how to explore solutions to the problem.

### Feature Descriptor

You are constructing an image feature consisting of the distances between skeleton intersection points. This is an unusual approach and a very interesting one. It reminds me of peak constellations, a feature used by Shazam to audio-fingerprint songs. If you are interested in exploring, that more sophisticated technique, take a look at ["An Industrial Strength Audio Search Algorithm"](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) by Avery Li-Chun Wang. I believe you could adapt their feature descriptor to your application.

However, if you want a simpler solution there are some other options as well. Your current descriptor uses `unique` to find a set of unique distances between the skeleton intersection points. Take a look at the following images of a line and an equilateral triangle both with 5 unit line lengths. If we use the unique distances between vertices to make the feature, the two images have identical features, but we can also count the number of lines of each length in a histogram.

[image: Simple feature example]

The histogram preserves more of the image structure as part of the feature. Using a histogram might help distinguish better between your similar and dissimilar cases.

Here's some demo code for histogram features using the Matlab demo images pears.png and peppers.png. I had difficulty extracting the skeleton from your provided images, but you should be able to adapt this code easily to your application.

```
I1 = = im2bw(imread('peppers.png'));
I2 = = im2bw(imread('pears.png'));
I1_skel = bwmorph(I1,'skel',Inf);
I2_skel = bwmorph(I2,'skel',Inf);
[i1,j1] = ind2sub(size(I1_skel),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(I1_skel,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
[i2,j2] = ind2sub(size(I2_skel),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(I2_skel,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));

%You used a for loop to find the distance between each pair of
%intersections. There is a function for this. 
d1 = round(pdist2([i1, j1], [i1, j1]));
d2 = round(pdist2([i2, j2], [i2, j2]));

%Choose a number of bins for the histogram. 
%This will be the length of the feature. 
%More bins will preserve more structure. 
%Fewer bins will help generalize between similar but not identical images.
num_bins = 100; 

%Instead of using `unique` to remove repetitions use `histcounts` in R2014b 
%feature1 = histcounts(d1(:), num_bins);
%feature2 = histcounts(d2(:), num_bins);

%Use `hist` for pre R2014b Matlab versions
feature1 = hist(d1(:), num_bins);
feature2 = hist(d2(:), num_bins);

%Normalize the features
feature1 = feature1 ./ norm(feature1);
feature2 = feature2 ./ norm(feature2);

figure; bar([feature1; feature2]'); 
title('Features'); legend({'Feature 1', 'Feature 2'}); 
xlim([0, num_bins]);
```

Here are what the detected intersection points are in each image
[image: Binary images and intersection points in skeleton]

Here are the resulting features. You can see the clear differences between images. 
[image: Histogram feature]

### Feature Comparison

The second part to consider is how you compare your features. Currently, you are simply looking for >20 similar distances. With the 'peppers.png' and 'pears.png' test images distributed with Matlab, I find more than 2000 intersection points in one image and 260 in the other. With so many points, it is trivial to have an overlap of >20 similar distances. In your images, the number of intersection points is much smaller. You could carefully adjust the threshold of similar distances, but I think this metric is probably to simplistic.

In Machine Learning, a simple way to compare two feature vectors is vector similarity or distance. There are multiple distance metrics you could explore. Common ones include

1. Cosine Distance

---

```
score_cosine = feature1 * feature2'; %Cosine distance between vectors

%Set a threshold for cosine similarity [0, 1] where 1 is identical and 0 is perpendicular
cosine_threshold = .9;
disp('Cosine Compare')
disp(score_cosine)
if score_cosine > cosine_threshold
    disp('similar images');
else
    disp('dissimilar images');
end
```

2. Euclidean Distance

---

```
score_euclidean = pdist2(feature1, feature2);

%Set a threshold for euclidean similarity where smaller is more similar
euclidean_threshold = 0.1;
disp('Euclidean Compare')
disp(score_euclidean)
if score_euclidean < euclidean_threshold
    disp('similar images');
else
    disp('dissimilar images');
end
```

If these don't work, you may need to train a classifier to find a more complicated function to distinguish between similar and dissimilar images.

Comment: Thanks @Cecilia for the try. I tried your version of code on my images. Keeping threshold  to 90% it didnt work well for me. All the similar images were identified as dissimilar ones. So i changed the threshold to 0.5. At this point all the dissimilar images are identified as similar images. n so i went for 0.6, 0.55. Result was same. I have added my images in this post. Is this happening because of the intersection points that are generated.   First and third images are similar

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI I gave it another try, but I think you may end up needing a classifier. I wasn't able to find a good threshold myself. I've added a whole lot more detail, so that you can explore all the avenues yourself.

Comment: thanks a ton for  these informations. I will for sure dive into these informations. But could you please help me to find a solution in these skeletonized images. I have asked a question  on this also but didn't get any favourable answer. I find some unnecessary branches while skeletonizing. How can I get rid of them. I guess before diving into extraction I need to clear it up.  Thanks a ton..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166166/unwanted-branches-in-thinning-process.