# Unwanted branches in thinning process

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to code for thinning an image and to an extent I got an output. But still the final output does have some small unwanted lines emerging from different areas.  My next step was to find intersection points. Because of these small lines, I get points which are actually not intersection points. How can I improve my code in order to avoid those lines.

```
I = imread('img.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
I = uint8(255*mat2gray(I));
I=imresize(I,[128 128]);

I1=edge(I,'canny',0.6);
I2=edge(I,'canny',0.1);
I = imsubtract(I2,I1);


si = imdilate(I,strel('line',3,0));
se = imerode(I,strel('line',3,0));
I = imsubtract(si,se);

si = imdilate(I,strel('disk',1));
se = imerode(I,strel('disk',3));
I = imsubtract(si,se);

I = imfill(I,'holes');


[L num]=bwlabel(I); %%number of connected objects found in binary%%%
A=[];
for i=1:num
    a=find(L==i);
    A(i)=size(a,1);
end
[b indxA]=max(A);

L2(128,128)=0;

for i=1:num
   if A(i)>=0.9*b
      L2(find(L==i))=1;
   end
end

I = imerode(L2,strel('disk',1));
I = bwmorph(I,'skel',Inf);

[i,j] = ind2sub(size(I),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(I,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
figure,imshow(I); hold on; plot(j,i,'rx');
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Required img:

[image]

Comment: Which of those lines are unwanted? Can you show a comparison with what you have-> what you want?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have added the required image.

Comment: Are you trying to detect the veins in the hand? I ask because it's not clear to me how to visually distinguish the required lines from the extra lines that you don't want in the original color image. If you just want to remove any short line, why is there still a small fork near the top of the required image?

Comment: yes am trying to detect the veins,That fork is a mistake. sorry I forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach has three key steps

1. Identify intersections between lines. `bwmorph` has a `branchpoint` option, but it wasn't aggressive enough. I used `conv2` to count neighboring pixels instead
2. Group pixels into line segments using `bwconncomp`
3. Use threshold to remove small line segments while checking that the image remains connected.

I've used a simple threshold of 10 pixels. If you want an adaptive threshold, you could use a metric relative to the length of the median or mean line segment. Choosing the threshold depends greatly on how much variation you have in your dataset. If there is too much variation, you might need human interaction for each image.

---

```
%Start off with your code above then do the following

%I got a better starting image with the 'thin' option than the 'skel' option
I = bwmorph(I,'thin',Inf);

%Alternative splitting method to 'branchpoint'
%Use convolution to identify points with more than 2 neighboring pixels
filter = [1 1 1;
          1 0 1;
          1 1 1];

I_disconnect = I & ~(I & conv2(double(I), filter, 'same')>2);

cc = bwconncomp(I_disconnect);
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,cc.PixelIdxList);
[sorted_px, ind] = sort(numPixels);

%Remove components shorter than threshold
threshold  = 10;
for ii=ind(sorted_px<threshold)
    cur_comp = cc.PixelIdxList{ii};
    I(cur_comp) = 0; 

    %Before removing component, check whether image is still connected
    full_cc = bwconncomp(I);
    if full_cc.NumObjects>1
        I(cur_comp) = 1; 
    end
end

%Clean up left over spurs
I = bwmoph(I, 'spur');
figure; imshow(I);
```

The output image is very similar to your desired output

[image: Output image]

Comment: @Cecilia...thanks for an amazing answer...Just one doubt in that code. Can we take that threshold automatically because a constant threshold may not work in all images. I tried this code on different images. So I thought of it. Second thing if the illumination is slightly varying in images, can we compensate that? I have done the normalization.But will that be enough? I guess am asking a lot but its getting interesting :-)

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI You will need to adjust the threshold for other images. If you are lucky, your images should be similar enough that you can find one that works for all of them. As far as illumination, it depends on how much it changes. You might need to change your method or thresholds. If you taking the photo yourself, try to get good illumination as much as possible. There is not much I can say about these issues without reference to the dataset.

Comment: So you are saying that the only way to change the threshold is to adjust it manually and there can't be any dependent feature based on which this threshold can be changed automatically? All your informations are appreciable. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI I've added a bit more explanation of the threshold in the answer. There is no one-size fits all solution for thresholds. If you're lucky a simple linear threshold will work. You can try adaptive thresholds based on the average length of lines in the image or some other image feature, but you first have to identify a relevant feature by examining your dataset and the failure cases in detail. I can't provide many suggestions because I don't know what the rest of your data looks like. Manual inspection is your best bet.

Comment: will work on it. Thanks a lot for the valuable informations, Good to know you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with skeleton image when i was working with finger vein recognition

```
function [ unbrachImg ] = removingSmallBraches( image ,brnchsize)
%Removing Small Branches from skelton image and also removes small loops 
%   Detailed explanation goes here

% image=bwmorph(bwmorph(image,'dilate',1),'erode',1);
% 
% image=bwmorph(bwmorph(image,'dilate',1),'skel','Inf');

Dmask=zeros(size(image));
B =  bwmorph(image,'branchpoints');
D = bwdistgeodesic(image,find(B),'quasi');
    Dmask(D < 2) =true;
    skelD=image-Dmask;

img1=bwmorph(image,'spur',brnchsize);

Dmask=zeros(size(img1));
B =  bwmorph(img1,'branchpoints');
D = bwdistgeodesic(img1,find(B),'quasi');
    Dmask(D < 2) =true;
    Dmask1=img1-Dmask;
brach=xor(img1,Dmask1);

unbrachImg=bwareaopen( skelD|brach|Dmask1,10);

unbrachImg=bwareaopen(unbrachImg,10);


end
```

It will result like that

[Orignal Skelton Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4eJt.png)

[After Applying this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLv4M.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could comment /explain the various steps in your code, also to help people like me who may be interested in your approach but use other tools (e.g. Python instead of Matlab).